# nVIDIA X Server Settings: making the right monitor to be at 0, 0

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have two monitors hooked up to my GT 630 running on Ubuntu 12.10. I have a 4:3 display on the left and a 16:9 display on my front (the main display).
Some fullscreen games launch the game at co-ordinates 0, 0 which is the top left corner of my LEFT DISPLAY. I obviously want to launch them on my main display, but its' topleft is 1280, 0.

I tried to set the LEFT monitor's co-ordinates to -1280, 0 and the main monitor to 0, 0 but it resets the left monitor to 0, 0 , probably meaning you can't set a monitor to a negative co-ordinate.

How can I get my main monitor to be at 0, 0 while still having the same monitor setup? (I can't put the secondary monitor to my right, my desk doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the 'Set this display as my primary device' setting in `nvidia-xserver-settings` (On mobile so wording may vary)

Comment: I have already done this. It still doesn't work on some games, tho, and i know that it is because the origin isn't where it usually is. Games like Super Hexagon try to launch on the wrong monitor.

Comment: Ahh, Super Hex. That's a [known issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1612OAYMsw) and fairly common among GLUT games.

Comment: Also affects Metro: Last Light, Open Hexagon amd Hotline Miami